# Converting multiple boolean columns to single factor column

Tags: r, matrix, multiple-columns

my data frame look like this:

```
      A S1 S2 S3 S4
1   ex1  1  0  0  0
2   ex2  0  1  0  0
3   ex3  0  0  1  0
4   ex4  1  0  0  0
5   ex5  0  0  0  1
6   ex6  0  1  0  0
7   ex7  1  0  0  0
8   ex8  0  1  0  0
9   ex9  0  0  1  0
10 ex10  1  0  0  0
```

i need to have it as a single factor list like:

```
A   Type
ex1 S1
ex2 S2
ex3 S3
ex4 S1
ex5 S4
ex6 S2
ex7 S1
ex8 S2
ex9 S3
ex10 S1
```

anybody help my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `d` is the data, the new column could be obtained with

```
d$type <- names(d[-1])[apply(d[-1] == 1, 1, which)]
d[c(1, 6)]
#       A type
# 1   ex1   S1
# 2   ex2   S2
# 3   ex3   S3
# 4   ex4   S1
# 5   ex5   S4
# 6   ex6   S2
# 7   ex7   S1
# 8   ex8   S2
# 9   ex9   S3
# 10 ex10   S1
```

Comment: +1, nice! Just one question: is it fully vectorized although you also use `apply` in your answer?

Comment: well, not fully.  But a lot of times you can put `sapply` and `apply` in there to make it faster.

Comment: Hm, I can imagine that using `sapply` instead of `apply` (where possible) is faster, but what do you mean by using `apply` to make it faster? Not sure I understand.

Comment: I mean when it's between the `[` and `]`

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that's what you mean. You're right there - good point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` and check the max in the columns 2-5 and then return the corresponding column name:

```
df$Type <- apply(df[2:5], 1, function(x) names(df)[which.max(x)+1] )
```

Afterwards, you can delete the columns you don't need anymore:

```
df <- df[,-c(2:5)]
```

Comment: its working for small datasets with 5 columns, but when with large dataset its throwing error "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable". Any idea

Comment: Not sure, did you check that all relevant columns are either `logical` or `numeric` or `integer`? As long as the input is the same type, there should be no problems with larger data sets.

Answer (score 2):

Could also do (if `dat` is your data set)

```
library(reshape2)
dat <- melt(dat, id = "A")
dat[dat$value > 0, 1:2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
If `df` is the dataframe

```
data.frame(A=df$A, Type=rep(names(df)[-1], nrow(df))[!!t(df[,-1])])
    A Type
1   ex1   S1
2   ex2   S2
3   ex3   S3
4   ex4   S1
5   ex5   S4
6   ex6   S2
7   ex7   S1
8   ex8   S2
9   ex9   S3
10 ex10   S1
```

Also:

```
   names(df)[-1][t(df[-1])*seq_len(ncol(df)-1)]
 [1] "S1" "S2" "S3" "S1" "S4" "S2" "S1" "S2" "S3" "S1"
```