# Convert Boolean indicator columns to a single factor column

Tags: r

A similar questions was asked a few years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361120/r-converting-multiple-boolean-columns-to-single-factor-column).

My setting is a little different. My indicator variables are not "true" dummy variables because they overlap.

I would like to do the following:

```r
# fake data
library(tibble)
dat <- tribble(
  ~"a", ~"b", ~"c",
  0,  0,   0,
  1, 0, 0,
  1, 1, 1
)
dat
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0     0     0
#> 2     1     0     0
#> 3     1     1     1

# desired data
desired_col <- c("none", "a", "a,b,c")
cbind(dat, desired_col)
#>   a b c desired_col
#> 1 0 0 0        none
#> 2 1 0 0           a
#> 3 1 1 1       a,b,c
```

Created on 2018-10-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Note that the column names are being pasted as character values in `desired_col`. If no values are present the value == `none`. If multiple values are present the values are separated with `,`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried `case_when`, but in reality I have many columns. Using `case_when` for so many interactions did not seem like a good way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using tidyverse functions

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% # keep data for each row together
  gather("col", "val", -rowid) %>% 
  mutate(rowid=factor(rowid)) %>% 
  filter(val==1) %>% 
  group_by(rowid) %>% 
  summarize(desired=paste(col, collapse=",")) %>%  #collapse values
  complete(rowid, fill = list(desired="none")) # add "none" for empty groups

#   rowid desired
#   <fct> <chr>  
# 1 1     none   
# 2 2     a      
# 3 3     a,b,c
```

The basic idea involves reshaping the data so we can run functions of groups rather than running functions over rows of a data.frame which isn't as easy.